# Angular, Cant reach Object Arrays content

Tags: angular

I want to use a crypto coin api and i get data from server to my **"_coins:coin[]"** list. I tried **"Console.log(_coins)"** , console shows the array, also I can open this list at html page with **"*ngFor"** but i cant open at .ts file.

i tried this at component

```
public _coins:coin[]=[];
  constructor(private _coinrepo:CoinRepository) {
    this._coins=this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC","ETH"]);
    console.log(this._coins);
   }
```

and at console:

```
Array []​
0: Object { KEY: "BTC", BTC: 1, USD: 10018.38, … }
1: Object { KEY: "ETH", BTC: 0.02072, USD: 207.49, … }
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
```

but i tried

```
public _coins:coin[]=[];
  constructor(private _coinrepo:CoinRepository) {
    this._coins=this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC","ETH"]);
    this._coins.forEach(i=>{
      console.log(i);
    });
   }
```

and at console **nothing**. I also tried for loop, .find, .pop ... nothing work. i want to take data like :

```
for(let item of this._coins){
      _btc=item.BTC;
      _usd=item.USD;
    }
```

Please help me..
codes are here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejrojd?embed=1

Comment: Can you check if this is also printing:

    public _coins:coin[]=[];        constructor(private _coinrepo:CoinRepository) { 
this._coins=this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC";"ETH"]); 
if (this._coins) console.log(this._coins); }

Comment: `this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC","ETH"])` - Is this returns an observable? or plain array? If it returns an observable then you need to subscribe. In HTML it is working because you might be using `async` pipe. Also Is there any error on console?

Comment: @user2216584 it returns array used subscribe method before returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return an array [or subscribe in the service] from the `this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC","ETH"])`, instead you should return an observable and then subscribe in the component. Because `this.restService.getMultiCoin(c_list.toString())` is an async call which will not immediately return. Change your method like this:

```
 getMultiCoins(c_list:string[]): Observable<coin[]>{
    return this.restService.getMultiCoin(c_list.toString())
        .pipe(
          map(apiRes => {

            for (let item in apiRes) {
               this.coins.push(
                { KEY: item, BTC: apiRes[item].BTC, USD: apiRes[item].USD, EUR: apiRes[item].EUR, TRY: apiRes[item].TRY }
            )
        }                
            return this.coins;
          })
        )
 }
```

Now in you component subscribe to the Observable returned from `getMultiCoins` API to unwrap the `coins` array like this:

```
public _coins:coin[]=[];
  constructor(private _coinrepo:CoinRepository) {
    this._coinrepo.getMultiCoins(["BTC","ETH"]).subscribe((coins) => {
      this._coins = coins;
        this._coins.forEach(i=>{
        console.log(i);
      });
     }
    );        
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for answer its very illustrative but i get **"ERROR TypeError: "apiRes.map is not a function"**

Comment: @cglyn_kya looks like your `this.restService.getMultiCoin(c_list.toString())` does not return an array[instead it returns an object]. I have changed my code to the same code which was there in your subscribe method i.e. `for` loop. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: it works :) i understand i must do my work in subscribe method. In subscribe i can now reach all but outside the subscribe not work. thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an Object you can't iterate it using for loop or forEach, try this code:

```
for(const key in this._coins){
     console.log("key : ", key , " val : ", this._coins[key]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the getMultiCoins method returns an array? This seems like a method that would be async so it would return a promise or an observable.

Comment: @AdrianBrand yes the method returns coin[] array used .subscribe before return

Comment: async doesn't work like that, if you subscribe in the getMultiCoins the call hasn't finished before you return and your array is empty.